# RESTful Web Services from Entity Classes

Tags: web-services, rest, netbeans

I want to implement restful web-services to query my database.

In Netbeans I did this:
- I created entity classes from my db
- I generated web-services from these entity classes

GET methods work fine when testing but I have some additional requirements. I dont want to query only by tables' id-s. Data needs to be retrieved also when some other parametres are entered.

For example I have a table:
Customer: id, name, address, country

Now I want to display all customers from a specific country.

Where in code can I achieve that?

Comment: did my answer help you solve your problem? If so - would you please accept my answer? It'll help with you accept-rate too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with slightly different urls.

So for a single customer you'd present a URL such as:

```
GET /customer/123.html
```

But for multiple customers, you'd figure out a way to specify groups. If you wanted all customers, you'd go for:

```
GET /customers.html
```

But say you grouped by country, you could try:

```
GET /customers/Australia.html
```

Using the singular or plural form would separate the two types of get-requests.